# Clarifying syntax on Lambda Expression

Tags: java, sorting, multidimensional-array, lambda, comparator

I am using below code to sort a 2D array by column, it is taking a lambda expression in the second parameter. I don't quite understand how (a,b) is defined and how a[0] and b[0] is working in the comparator. This code is sorting correctly, but I want to understand the syntax. Thanks.

```
   Arrays.sort(myArray, (a, b) -> Integer.compare(a[0], b[0]))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 2D array by column

Java doesn't have 2D arrays. It has arrays of arrays, and some syntax sugar to let you declare an array-of-arrays and immediately initialize the outer array by creating new arrays and filling the slots.

```
int[][] grid = new int[10][5];
```

is syntax sugar for:

```
int[][] grid = new int[10][];
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) grid[i] = new int[5];
```

> `Arrays.sort(myArray, (a, b) -> Integer.compare(a[0], b[0]))`

The type of myArray is `int[][]`. In other words, an array of `int[]`. Thus, to sort this, you need to provide an oracle: This oracle needs to be capable of giving consistent answers to the question: "Given 2 components (in this case, the component is `int[]`), tell me if the first component sorts 'after' the second, or 'before' the second, or sorts equally. Do so by returning a negative number to indicate that the first is 'before', a positive number to indicate the first is 'after', and 0 to indicate they are equal or at least sort-ordering-wise at an equal level.

Ordinarily, you'd do this by creating an implementation of the `Comparator<int[]>` interface, creating an instance of this, and passing it along:

```
class MySorter implements Comparator<int[]> {
    @Override public int compare(int[] a, int[] b) {
        return Integer.compare(a[0], b[0]);
    }
}

MySorter mySorter = new MySorter();
Arrays.sort(myArray, mySorter);
```

The above code works fine - you can compile and run it.

Lambdas aren't much different from what is happening above. There is only one relevant `sort` method on Arrays, and it indeed does take 2 arguments: An array of `T`, and a `Comparator` that can compare `T`, with T being whatever you please (here, T is `int[]`). So why can you pass a lambda there?

Because the compiler works outside-in. It initially just sees:

```
Arrays.sort(myArray, someLambdaExpressionIHaveNotLookedAtYet)
```

and will stop right there, and try to figure out which method is intended. It'll find that only one method 'works': `public static <T> sort (T[] array, Comparator<T> comparator)`.

Only then does javac continue: First, it checks that Comparator is a so-called 'single abstract method' type (a SAM type): It is; Comparator is an interface that defines just a single method*, which means it is a SAM type, which means you can shortcut the creation of a class that `implements` this interface, along with creating a new instance of this class, into a one-liner.

Now, *because* java already knows what the lambda is supposed to represent (namely, an implementation for `Comparator<int[]>`, and it knows there is only one method that you're trying to implement (namely, `public int compare(int[] a, int[] b)`), **java already knows the variable types**. The method you're implementing *has* to be `int[] a, int[] b`.

That's why you don't have to specify it. You can just write `(a, b)` - java fills in the `int[]` for you. You CAN write it out: Give it shot, write `Arrays.sort(myArray, (int[] a, int b[]) -> Integer.compare(a[0], b[0])` and you'll find it works exactly the same way.

The rest is trivial: `->` is just lambda syntax, and because you don't write a `{` immediately afterwards, the single expression that follows the -> is just inserted as return value.

Thus,

`(a, b) -> Integer.compare(a[0], b[0])`

is 100% equivalent to:

```
public class A implements B {
    public C {
        return D;
    }
}
A a = new A();
```

Where:

- A = a randomly chosen irrelevant name,
- B = the type that is expected there
- C = a copy of the one method defined in B (and if there is not one method, you can't use this syntax),
- D = whatever you wrote after the ->.

*) Methods that are already defined in java.lang.Object don't count, and methods with default impls also don't count.

Comment: @user15358848 Thanks for the headsup. I should just remember 'the syntax is precisely incorrect because reasons' and then I won't mess it up again :)

Answer (score 1):

[`Arrays.sort(T[] a, Comparator<? super T> c)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort-T:A-java.util.Comparator-) takes a [`Comparator<T>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) as the second argument, which declares the method [`int compare(T o1, T o2)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#compare-T-T-).

That means the lambda expression must implement that method, and with `myArray` being an `Integer[][]` or `int[][]`, it means that `T` is an `Integer[]` or `int[]`, so both `a` and `b` are `Integer[]` or `int[]`.

The statement will therefore sort the 2D array by the first column.